# Error: node not installed after updated homebrew on mac M1

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew, apple-m1

After I updated homebrew, I can't use homebrew to upgrade node. It can't find node.

### Updated Brew on mac M1

After getting this error

```sh
Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!
Please create a new installation in /opt/homebrew using one of the
"Alternative Installs" from:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
You can migrate your previously installed formula list with:
  brew bundle dump
```

I updated homebrew using:

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"` for my mac M1.

Then I followed the instructions for two commands brew said to run.

Then I ran these commands:

`$ cd ~`

`$ brew bundle dump`

**UPDATE:** `$ brew bundle dump` didn't do what I expected. When I look in `/opt/homebrew/bin` not all of the contents from `/usr/local/bin` are there, but I would expect them to move there.

### Now Brew can't find node

`$ brew upgrade node`

Gave me:
`Error: node not installed`

but `$ node -v` gives

`v12.6.0`

And the BrewFile that `$ brew bundle dump` created shows node: `brew "node"`.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood what `brew bundle dump` does. It only creates a file that says the packages that brew should install.

BrewFile works like a package.json file in node.js. You have to run `brew bundle install` to install the packages listed in BrewFile.

So my node package was still in the old location `usrs/local/bin` and node was not in `opt/homebrew/bin` where it should be.

To fix, I moved the BrewFile into the new brew location `opt/homebrew` then ran `brew bundle install` from in that directory. Now node is in the correct place `opt/homebrew/bin` along with all my other brew packages.

Now `which node` gives:

`/opt/homebrew/bin/node`

It looks like this also updated node. But you have to open a new terminal. `node -v` will then show the newly instaled version. Your old version is still in `usrs/local/bin` but it looks like the paths corrected for me.